# Entity Framework migration with already deployed SQL compact database

Tags: sql, entity-framework, deployment, entity-framework-4, sql-server-ce

My situation: EF 4.3, private install of SQL Compact 4, .Net FW 4, c# winform

Problem: after the application was deployed there was the inevitable change requested that required me to create a new field in the only table in the SQL compact database. During app install the SQL compact db is placed in the user's Application Data folder so that it can be written to successfully. I updated the program and redeployed but the following behaviors are occurring:

- uninstalling the old version of the app does not uninstall the SQL compact db in the user's Application Data folder
- installing the updated version of the application does not overwrite the old SQL Compact db in the user's Application.

Since the new database with the added column doesn't get copied over it is breaking the application when the user runs it. My reaearch indicates that I should be using "automatic EF migrations" to solve my problem. In my situation mydesired strategy would be to do a quick check of the db table and add the missing column if necessary.

I am using EF the Database first way. I am having a hard time finding a good example that fits my situation and my desired strategy for fixing this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think EF Migrations have anything to do with your problem. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2261556/how-does-the-clickonce-installer-handle-updates-when-a-compact-database-is-invol), if you follow ClickOnce tutorials step by step, it should work. As suggested by that SO answer, you should check [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8saf4wy.aspx). Good luck!